# Need to filter MySQL results based on date relative to other dates in the same column/table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
ID (int) (PK)
PersonID (int)
EventDate (date)
```

What I need to do is retrieve all PersonID's where there is an EventDate within 14 days of another EventDate.

```
Sample Data:
ID    PersonID    EventDate
1     101         2011-01-01
2     102         2011-02-01
3     103         2011-03-01
4     104         2011-04-01
5     105         2011-04-11
6     106         2011-04-21
7     107         2011-05-01
8     108         2011-06-01
9     109         2011-07-01
10    110         2011-08-01

Desired Results:
104
105
106
107
```

I have not been able to figure out any way to go about this.

I could do it in PHP, but would much prefer a way to do this in MySQL directly.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should work for you

```
// #1  - quite slow 
SELECT a.PersonID, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM table1 b WHERE b.ID != a.ID
  AND a.EventDate BETWEEN 
   (b.EventDate - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND b.EventDate + INTERVAL 14 DAY)
 ) as cnt  
FROM table1 a  
HAVING cnt >0
// or  #2 - should be much faster 
SELECT DISTINCT a.PersonID
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON (b.ID != a.ID AND a.EventDate BETWEEN 
   (b.EventDate - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND b.EventDate + INTERVAL 14 DAY))
```

Comment: #2 works perfectly after removing the () around the BETWEEN argument.  Thank you.  I also feel like an idiot for forgetting about joining the table to itself. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

This gets close:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.PersonID, child.PersonID, DATEDIFF(parent.EventDate, child.EventDate) AS diff
FROM testdata AS parent
JOIN testdata AS child ON ABS(DATEDIFF(parent.EventDate, child.EventDate)) < 14
WHERE (parent.personID <> child.personID)
```

using

```
mysql> select * from testdata;
+------+----------+---------------------+
| ID   | PersonID | EventDate           |
+------+----------+---------------------+
|    1 |      101 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 |
|    2 |      102 | 2011-02-01 00:00:00 |
|    3 |      103 | 2011-03-01 00:00:00 |
|    4 |      104 | 2011-04-01 00:00:00 |
|    5 |      105 | 2011-04-11 00:00:00 |
|    6 |      106 | 2011-04-21 00:00:00 |
|    7 |      107 | 2011-05-01 00:00:00 |
|    8 |      108 | 2011-06-01 00:00:00 |
|    9 |      109 | 2011-07-01 00:00:00 |
|   10 |      110 | 2011-08-01 00:00:00 |
+------+----------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT parent.PersonID, child.PersonID, DATEDIFF(parent.EventDate, child.EventDate) AS diff FROM testdata AS parent JOIN testdata AS child ON ABS(DATEDIFF(parent.EventDate, child.EventDate)) < 14 WHERE (parent.personID <> child.personID);
+----------+----------+------+
| PersonID | PersonID | diff |
+----------+----------+------+
|      105 |      104 |   10 |
|      104 |      105 |  -10 |
|      106 |      105 |   10 |
|      105 |      106 |  -10 |
|      107 |      106 |   10 |
|      106 |      107 |  -10 |
+----------+----------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Right now the drawback is that it sees 105/104 as being different from 104/105 (which they are, but merely as mirror images of each other).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do this this way:

```
$data   = array(...); // fetched data
$result = array();

$tmp = array();
foreach ( $data as $row ) {
  $timestamp = strtotime($row['EventDate']);
  $tmp[ $timestamp ] = $row;
}
ksort($tmp);

$prevRow = array();
$prevTimestamp = 0;
$diff = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; // 14 days
$prevMatched = true;

foreach ( $tmp as $timestamp => $row ) {

  if ( empty($prevTimestamp) ) {
    $prevRow = $row;
    $prevTimestamp = $timestamp;
    continue;
  }

  if ( ( $timestamp - $prevTimestamp ) <= $diff ) {

    $result[] = $row;
    $prevMatched = true;

  } else {

    if ( $prevMatched ) {
      $result[] = $prevRow;
    }

    $prevMatched = false;
  }

}

var_dump($result);
```